# getting equation of a line between 2 points in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv3.0

I have two points in the image, let's say (30, 220) and (1385, 1050). I want to find the equation that is passing through these two points. I can draw the line with OpenCV's library in python.

> ```
> cv.line(frame, (30, 220),  (1385, 1050), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)
> ```

**PS.**  My ultimate goal is to calculate the lowest distance between a point and that line.

Comment: these are your coordinates; (30, 220),  (1385, 1050) then use the formula y = mx + b  where m is the slope and b is the intercept

Answer (score 3):

Here how I find it:

```html
from numpy import ones,vstack
from numpy.linalg import lstsq
import math

points = [(30, 220),(1385, 1050)]
x_coords, y_coords = zip(*points)
A = vstack([x_coords,ones(len(x_coords))]).T
m, c = lstsq(A, y_coords)[0]
print("Line Solution is y = {m}x + {c}".format(m=m,c=c))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

Find the slope `m = (y_1 - y_2)/(x_1 - x_2)`, then solve the equation `y = mx + b` for `b` using `y_1` for `y`, and `x_1` for `x` (or you can use your second coordinate).